# Sorting metrics by service?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, promql

I need to setup monitoring for a large app that lives on an equally large K8S cluster. Because of how this app and the corresponding infrastructure were set up, i need to be able to monitor pods according to services (in the K8S).

I would normally do something like :

```sql
sum (rate (container_network_transmit_bytes_total[1m])) by (service)
```

But that doesn't return anything. Would anybody have a better method ?

Comment: How do you identify the service ? With the instance name ? It would be easier with a sample of `container_network_transmit_bytes_total`

Comment: That's juste the question i'm asking myself. Only the *_info metrics seem to include services as Kubernetes understands them. The others include services as Prometheus understands them, which basically means the exporter it's scraping metrics from

Comment: OK I ended up getting it. The label i am looking for is not exported, so i have to use replace_label. And Bob's your uncle

Comment: Can't you inject it in your service discovery ? Or use `relabel_configs` in Prometheus ?